# Reset pandas Timestamp to first day of month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

`df` is a pandas data frame. The column `df["Date"]` is a datetime field.

```
test_date = df.loc[300, "Date"]  # Timestamp('2019-02-12 00:00:00')
```

I want to reset it back to the first day. I tried:

```
test_date.day = 1  # Attribute 'day' of 'datetime.date' objects is not writable
```

How can I reset it back to the first day (preferably without loading other libraries)?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42602347/rolling-a-datetimeindex-forward-to-the-beginning-of-the-next-business-month-in-p) is similar to what I want to do, but it uses Python 2 and an older version of pandas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be looking for `test_date = test_date.replace(day=1)`.

[datetime.date.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace)

Answer (score 4):

Sample dataframe as:

```
di

Out[708]:
                          0
0 2014-08-25 10:00:00+05:30
1 2014-08-26 10:00:00+05:30
2 2014-08-27 10:00:00+05:30
3 2014-08-28 10:00:00+05:30
4 2014-08-29 10:00:00+05:30
5 2014-08-30 10:00:00+05:30
6 2014-08-31 10:00:00+05:30
7 2014-09-01 10:00:00+05:30
8 2014-09-02 10:00:00+05:30
9 2014-09-03 10:00:00+05:30
```

To get first date of month:

```
di[0].dt.date + pd.offsets.Day() - pd.offsets.MonthBegin()

Out[709]:
0   2014-08-01
1   2014-08-01
2   2014-08-01
3   2014-08-01
4   2014-08-01
5   2014-08-01
6   2014-08-01
7   2014-09-01
8   2014-09-01
9   2014-09-01
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: for me the following worked `di[0] + pd.offsets.Day() - pd.offsets.MonthBegin()`